# Save few values to the row in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to save few values to the row. For example, I have 2 tables:
For Participants:

```
CREATE TABLE participants (
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  uuid BIGINT UNIQUE
);
```

And for Voters:

```
CREATE TABLE voters (
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  uuid BIGINT UNIQUE,
  participants -> here I want to save all available uuid from participants table
);
```

I want to get array of participants uuid after executing  `SELECT participants FROM voters WHERE uuid='someuuid';`

Comment: You want multiple values in a single column? Use an array. But, are you 100% sure about this? It's a recipe for many nasty problems.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if you have a column named `uuid` you're probably better off using a `uuid`-typed column instead of `bigint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE voters (
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  uuid BIGINT UNIQUE,
  participants INT[]
);
```

then later use unnest function to expand the array to row records

```
SELECT unnest(participants)
FROM voters 
WHERE uuid='someuuid'
```